# Python Reversi/Othello AI working under 1 second

Tags: python, reversi

---

In an recent assignment we were given a task to create **Reversi/Othello AI** which can make a valid move under **1s**. I have started with a simple bot, which takes all available moves and scores them based on board with values. On the second bot I added also mobility value to the ranking. Now I have made a bot which searches with minmax 3 moves ahead and evaluates the moves based on score. My problem is, it gets beaten by the score/mobility one step ahead bot. Is it possible or did I code the AI wrong? Is it because I am searching only 3 steps ahead?

My bot starts with this:

```
possible_moves = self.get_available_moves(board,self.my_color,self.opponent_color)
for [x, y] in possible_moves:
    new_board = self.make_board_copy(board)
    new_board[x][y] = self.my_color
    new_alpha = self.minmax(new_board,1,alpha,beta)
    if new_alpha > alpha:
        alpha = new_alpha
        best_move = [x,y]
```

And then goes to this:

```
    def minmax(self, board, depth, alpha, beta):
    # END NODE
    if depth == self.max_depth:
        return self.evaluate(board)
    else:
        # MAX NODE = MY MOVE
        if depth % 2 == 0:
            possible_moves = self.get_available_moves(board,self.my_color,self.opponent_color)
            for [x, y] in possible_moves:
                new_board = self.make_board_copy(board)
                new_board[x][y] = self.my_color
                new_alpha = self.minmax(new_board,depth+1,alpha,beta)
                if new_alpha > alpha:
                    alpha = new_alpha
                if alpha > beta:
                    return alpha
            return alpha
        # MIN NODE
        else:
            possible_moves = self.get_available_moves(board,self.my_color,self.opponent_color)
            for [x,y] in possible_moves:
                new_board = self.make_board_copy(board)
                new_board[x][y] = self.my_color
                new_beta = self.minmax(new_board, depth + 1, alpha, beta)
                if new_beta < beta:
                    beta = new_beta
                if beta < alpha:
                    return beta
            return beta
```

I checked the code many times and still can't figure out if my code is bad or if the AI is getting beaten because it does not search deep enough.

Answer (score 1):

If it's using the same evaluation, I think it's unlikely that the lower depth search beats the higher depth search, and probably impossible.

Can you explain the alpha and beta, and the minmax functions a bit more, or show more code? Are both alpha and beta always positive?

I think there might be something wrong in your odd node function:

```
if new_beta < beta:
    beta = new_beta
if beta < alpha:
    return beta
```

If alpha and beta are both positive values, then you want the first line to be

```
if new_beta > beta:
```

It also depends how your score the board positionally. That's obviously very important - I don't know if your AI is trying to learn this from playing, or if you've given it an evaluation based on various positional factors and judgements.

Comment: The board scoring is hardcoded base on some table I have found on internet:

Comment: `    score_board = [[99, -8, 8, 6, 6, 8, -8, 99], [-8, -24, -4, -3, -3, -4, -24, -8], [8, -4, 7, 4, 4, 7, -4, 8],
                   [6, -3, 4, 0, 0, 4, -3, 6], [6, -3, 4, 0, 0, 4, -3, 6], [8, -4, 7, 4, 4, 7, -4, 8],
                   [-8, -24, -4, -3, -3, -4, -24, -8], [99, -8, 8, 6, 6, 8, -8, 99]]`

Comment: I have found my mistake. When I was making new node - making some move, I just placed it in but didnt flipped the stones that should have been flipped, now it works nice and smooth. Thank you anyway